# Comparing values after it changed by the user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function which triggered (it is called by the OnEdit(e) function) every-time there is a change in column 'K'.
essentially, this column is charged of gathering the information whether the specific call is open or closed (It's a CRM system)

this code working great but the info that is comparing is wrong - the compare if the value is 'closed' or not is made after the user change this value so it become irrelevant.

is there any way to make this compare before the user actually changing the value? or maybe to compare it to the value before it was changed?

```
function isClosedColumnChanged(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get Active cell
  var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  var isClosed = 'K' + (cellrow);

  if (cellcol == 11)
  {

    if (sheet.getRange(isClosed).getValue() == "closed")
    {
      messageit('its forbidden to close already-closed call');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect to reference the activecell / active sheet in an on-edit function when trying to determine new and old values. Use the event object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the on-edit trigger object: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Try changing from

```
if (cellcol == 11)
{
  if (sheet.getRange(isClosed).getValue() == "closed")
  {
    messageit('its forbidden to close already-closed call');
  }
}
```

To

```
if (e.range.getColumn() == 11) // If edited column is 11
{
  //If new value is closed and oldValue is also closed
  if (e.value == "closed" && e.oldValue == "closed")
  {
    messageit('its forbidden to close already-closed call');
  }
}
```

Note: Only ONE cell should be edited to avail `e.value` and `e.oldValue`:

> **oldValue**: Cell value prior to the edit, if any. Only available if the edited range is a single cell. Will be undefined if the cell had no previous content.
>
> **value**: New cell value after the edit. Only available if the edited range is a single cell.